# CSS Style for Search textbox

Tags: css

I am just trying to design my Search textbox like this

[image]

and I have tried like this,

```
border: none;
outline:none;
outline-offset: 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid;
border-color:#33B5E5;
padding:5px;
```

and I am getting like, [image]

I can give style and color for border-bottom, I don't know how to design that small line in both right and left sides. can anyone help me out here, thanks in advance

Comment: Create a demo in jsfiddle

Comment: I have a demo in jsFiddle, but am not able to provide the link here

Comment: save the jsfiddle and share the link here

Comment: @FLF, that's nice, this is the link  http://jsfiddle.net/shanish/5pqHD/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<div class="inputWrapper">
<input type="text">
</div>
```

and the css:

```
    .inputWrapper {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #009999;
  border-left: solid 1px #009999;
  border-right: solid 1px #009999;
  overflow: visible;
  max-height: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
}
input {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

The idea is basically to wrap the input with a wrapper which will have the lines of your style. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jBq4u/3/

Comment: Nice, except maybe make the wrapper relative and compensate for the offset of the input, otherwise your positioning will be a bit off.

Comment: but am not able to increase the height. If I increase the height, it affects the design, what to do?

Comment: you can increase the height of by editing the max-height property, then you can change the bottom position of the input to get everything  right.

Comment: Oh is it, I just tried increasing only the max-height of wrapper, I'll try adjusting the input also, thanks

Comment: I changed the example to this something bigger, have a look ;) http://jsfiddle.net/jBq4u/4/

Comment: that's nice, it looks cool, if you don't mind, can you help me to reduce the height of the borders in the both the sides??, its something like I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: I changed this way, just change the padding and max height http://jsfiddle.net/jBq4u/5/

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjlJv

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
   <input type="text" id="something" />
</div>
```

**css**

```
#container {
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-body;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 13%;
}

#something {
  border: none;
  outline:none;
  outline-offset: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-color:#33B5E5;
  padding:10px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create one background image like you need bottom line and put there in your class for textbox. it should work I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ikhanm/RvJFg/) comes a little close.

```
// HTML
<span class="l">&nbsp;</span>
<input type="textbox" id="tb"/>
<span class="r">&nbsp;</span>

// CSS
#tb{
    border: none;
outline:none;
outline-offset: 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid;
border-color:#33B5E5;
padding:5px;
    border-right : solid 1px #33B5E5;
    border-left : solid 1px #33B5E5;
}

span.l{
    position:relative;
    left : 10px;
    top:-2px;
    background-color:white;
}

span.r{
    position:relative;
    left : -10px;
    top:-2px;
    background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: Ya, its close, I just tried like this also, but I want that borders as it is in the image I have shared.... anyhow, Kicker's solution solved my issue, thanks for your help mohkhan.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using [Pseudo element](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp).

Comment: thanks dude, I have learned something new in CSS, thanks again

Comment: Alas, [pseudo elements don't work on `input` elements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2587669/419956).